# Is there a way to pass size to an array which is in node (C++ custom data container)

Tags: c++

I would like to pass size of an array which is a part of data container on constructing it. I am not allowed to use STL.

This is for my university subject homework program. I tried using constructor for that but it don't work.

```
struct T
{
    node *head, *tail;
    T()
    {
        head=NULL;
        tail=NULL;
    }
};

struct node
{
    int a;
    float array[a];
    node *next;
    node(int b) : a(b) {}
};

int main()
{
    ...
}
```

Code is incomplete because im stuck here. It's just to visualize what i want to achieve.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::vector`?  If so, use that instead

Comment: no, i can't use STL library. sorry, I forgot to mention about that.

Comment: You can't use 'a' in float array[a]; 'a' doesn't have a value at compile time, this has to be a const or a array has to be a pointer that's allocated at runtime.

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation with `new[]`? Pass the size as a template argument?

Comment: Use `std::array` or `std::vector`, *not* C-style arrays. And don't do manual memory management in modern C++, please. And `NULL` should be `nullptr`.

Comment: And a little nipicking: The "STL" is [the "Standard Template Library"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library), which was mostly a pre-cursor and inspiration for the standard C++ library. Much like Boost is today. Between the standard C++ library and Boost, STL is mostly obsolete today.

Comment: Standard workaround: write a `namespace not_allowed_std { template<typename T> class vector { /*members of std::vector here*/ }; }` and use that wherever you would otherwise be using `std::vector`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude And here I was thinking that the nitpicking was going to be about the "STL library" = "Standard Template Library library"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the struct replace `float array[a];` by  `float * array;`

```
struct node
{
    int a;
    float * array;
    node *next;
    node(int b) : a(b) {}
};
```

and you will be able to manage any size

you have to decide if the `float*` is given or not in parameter of node(), may be both :

```
struct node
{
    int a;
    float * array;
    node *next;
    node(int b, float * ar) : a(b), array(ar), next(NULL) {}
    node(int b) : a(b), next(NULL) { array = new float[a]; }
};
```

then a destructor is necessary to delete the array

```
struct node
{
    int a;
    float * array;
    node *next;

    node(int b, float * ar) : a(b), array(ar), next(NULL) {}
    node(int b) : a(b), next(NULL) { array = new float[a]; }
    ~node() { if (array != NULL) delete [] array; }
};
```

and more : copy constructor, operator=, depending on your version of C++ may be also the *move* etc

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. How does OP creates its array of `b` floats?

Comment: Then in your 'node' constructor 'array = new float[b]'; also added :next(nullptr) to your 'node' constructor'

Comment: Don't forget a `~node() {delete [] array;}` or memory will leak :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I just did ^^

Answer (score 1):

Use pointer to array and allocate in constructor and deallocate in destructor. Something like below.

```
float *array;
node(int b) : a(b)
{
    array = new float[b];
}

~node()
{
    delete[] array;
}
```

Comment: `array = new array[b];`  must be `array = new float[b];` ^^

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I am using Android app which is way too difficult to type.

Comment: Wow if you are on a phone I prefer to not imagine how it is ^^